# Varying ggplot scotterplot color by background variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a dataframe named df with following variables/columns: (age, salary, blood_type), and I currently have the scatterplot below:

```
  plotBTHistogram <- df %>% 
     ggplot(aes(y=age, x=salary)) + 
     geom_point(aes(x = salary), color = "darkred") +
     scale_x_log10(labels = scales::dollar, breaks = c(10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000)) +
     labs(x="Salary", y="Age")
     plotBTHistogram + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

How can I vary the color of my geom_points by blood_type category (not being plotted)?

Comment: put `color = blood_type` inside your `aes` call.

Comment: If I do that, I receive an error in layer indicating that the blood_type object is not found. I assume because we are only dealing with age and salary variables within the plot?

Comment: It'll be hard to help without a reproducible example. Can you please add the output of `dput(head(df))` into the body of your question? Then we could see how the `df` table is structured and test potential solutions.

Comment: Your aes(.) arguments should have something like `fill=blood_type`

Comment: Alright something else has to be going on, because if I do that, I get 
Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPoint, : object 'blood_type' not found, and it is a chr column in my list.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Problem was PEBKAC. I was utilizing the wrong AES line. Thanks all.